# How can I change the default python enviroment in VS2015?

Tags: python, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to modify the default Python compilation environment options in Visual Studio.

The option directory is at `Options -> Python Tools -> Environment Options`.

However, after I added a new custom environment, changed the default environment to the custom one, and clicked "OK" to save, I found that the settings go back to the default "Python 3.4".

How can I really save these changes?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is probably far too late, but I had this problem as well. I found the solution and that is to right click the "Python Environments" in the solution explorer of the project and add/remove python environments and then choose the one you're attempting to go to.